# How to add error handling in Jquery Ajax Form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

This is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#spc-comment-flag-form').submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            url: $(this).attr('action'), 
            success: function(data) {
                if( data['error'] == false) {
                    var msg = 'We got your flag. Our moderators will now look into it. You may close the window now!';
                    $('#spc-comment-flag-response').html(msg);
                }
                else {
                    $('#spc-comment-flag-response').html(data);
                }   
            },
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

**edit**

on server side its something like this:

```
@csrf_protect
@login_required
def flag(request, comment_id, next=None):
    if not request.is_ajax():
        raise Http404
    data = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ...
        data = simplejson.dumps(data)
        return HttpResponse(data, mimetype="application/javascript")
    else:
        raise Http404
```

I am basically server side guy and seldom have to write JS. 
I sent "error" : true if there is an error with error message and "error" : false if no error on server!

I don't know why in the above code the conditional logic is not working!!
Can anyone help me fix it?

Comment: aare you sending the response as JSON from the server ?? or is it just  HTML

Comment: What kind of the data are you sending back? JSON (`"error" : true` is not valid JSON)? If so, are you setting proper `Content-Type` response headers? Otherwise jQuery won't know that it is JSON and won't parse it automatically. Then you have to set the `dataType: 'json'` option.

Comment: sending response as JSON

Comment: Ok, so assuming that you are actually sending `{"error": true}`, add `dataType: 'json'` to the Ajax  call options.

Comment: please look into the question again, I added server side code

Comment: You are sending, JSON, not JavaScript. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/267546/218196. And as I said, if you set the option, it should already work.

Answer (score 8):

try this one...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#spc-comment-flag-form').submit(function() {
            $.ajax({
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                type: $(this).attr('method'),
                url: $(this).attr('action'), 
                success: function(data) {
                    if( data['error'] == false) {
                        var msg = 'We got your flag. Our moderators will now look into it. You may close the window now!';
                        $('#spc-comment-flag-response').html(msg);
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#spc-comment-flag-response').html(data);
                    }   
                },
                error: function (data) {
                       var r = jQuery.parseJSON(data.responseText);
                       alert("Message: " + r.Message);
                       alert("StackTrace: " + r.StackTrace);
                       alert("ExceptionType: " + r.ExceptionType);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: Is responseText always defined?

Answer (score 1):

You may use this code.. if you want to handle the error in web **request** ...

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({

}).done(function (data) {

}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {

});
```

And about in your server side validation you could return the error using **json**...

Comment: What do you put inside `$.ajax({

}` ?

Comment: @CyrilDuchon-Doris the data you are sending to the AJAX page. So in the OP's example, this would be data attribute i.e. `$(this).serialize()`

Answer (score 1):

you have to use

```
error: function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown){
   ...
   ...
}
```

[full documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

```
  success: function(data)
  {
    if(data.error){
       //alert error
    }
    else{
       //alert('Success');
    }
  },
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
  {
     alert('Internal server error');
     //some stuff on failure
  }
```

This `error` callback also handles the error, which are not caught at the server side.

Comment: Hey, if I put the `mimetype` or `content_type` in server its not working

Comment: I don't get it. Can you elaborate? What I mean is that if any uncaught exception comes on server side, then `error` callback will be called, not `success`.